# JQuery, PHP. Можно ли загружать файлы отправляемые на сервер по одному?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, хотел поинтересоваться у знающих людей: есть скрипт загрузки изображений на сервер, который сохраняет скопом N-ное количество файлов, и хотелось бы знать, можно ли отправлять картинки через JQuery по одному и возрастет ли в таком случае нагрузка на сервер?

Comment: Можно. Возрастёт.

Comment: Если это не сервис по заливке картинок, т.е. там нет картинок огромного размера и их не заливается по тысяче в минуту, то нагрузка возрастет незначительно.

Answer (score 0):

В чем проблема, можете отправлять хоть по одному, хоть десятком сразу (через multi-form, например). Естественно, в случае отправки по одному будет немного большая нагрузка на сервер (ввиду большего количества отправляемых запросов). Но обычно это не та разница, которая может быть существенной.